# Sort a List<string> according to another List<int>

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have two Lists:

```
student = new list<string>() {"Bob" , "Alice" , "Roger" , "Oscar"};

Marks = new list<int>() {80,95,70,85};
```

I want sort Student by Marks in fastest style and the expected output must be:

> Student = {"Alice","Oscar","Bob","Roger"}

Is there any command under list methods same as `list.sort` or `list.orderby` to achieve the goal?

Comment: Are you using .NET 4?  If so, I can provide a good answer using the Tuple class.

Comment: I would create an object, e.g. 'Participant' which has two members 'Score' and 'Mark'. And then you could easily sort them by 'Mark'.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use 2 arrays.

Your best approach is to use a class to store pairs of data.

```
public class Student
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Mark { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have an array of Student objects

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(...);
```

Then you can sort the names together with the marks

```
var sortedStudents = students.OrderBy(s => s.Mark).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Zip function together with Tuples.

```
student.Zip(Marks, (s, n) => new Tuple<string, int>(s,n)).Sort(t => t.Item2).Select(t => t.Item1);
```

Comment: A shorter way to write `new Tuple<string, int>(s,n)` is `Tuple.Create(s,n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Pair the name and score using the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Tuple<string, int>> list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Bob",80 ));
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Alice", 95));
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Roger", 70));
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Oscar", 85));

        // Use Sort method with Comparison delegate.
        // ... Has two parameters; return comparison of Item2 on each.
        list.Sort((a, b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2));

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
    }
}
```