# Sorting an array of ints using an array of floats

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, runtime

I'm trying to sort an array of floats, but somehow keep track of what each float's original position in the array was.
I'm trying to accomplish this by creating an array of ints where array[i] = i and then sorting that array of ints based on the array of floats.

the Array.Sort(Array, Array) looks like the way to go, so I call that method like so:

```
Array.Sort(ints, floats);
```

but I get a runtime error:

```
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
System.Array.Sort[Int32,Single] (System.Int32[] keys, System.Single[] items, Int32 index,        Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
```

I know this method works with two arrays of ints.

Otherwise, is there a better way to sort an array, but keep track of each item's original position?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show your `ints` and `floats` ?

Comment: There are many similar questions... Note that most likely correct approach is class that contains all necessary properties (index, values,...) instead of trying to sort multiple arrays together. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750549/sort-a-liststring-according-to-another-listint/16750589#16750589

Comment: Would just copying the array before sorting do what you need? That would be simpler you just want to know each items original position. I suppose it would depend on the specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the position of the float in your original array based on the float value try to use a dictionary!

```
float[] f = new float[] { 1.4f, 2.4f, 1.9f };
Dictionary<float, int> origPos = new Dictionary<float, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
{
    origPos[f[i]] = i;
}
Array.Sort(f);

int pos = origPos[f[1]];  // this way you can get the position of a float in the original array
```